# Condition with Watson conversation

Tags: watson-conversation

I have one Entity called Doctors with this value "Fabio" and Synonyms ("Cancer", "head", "legs"...)

So if my user say. "I want to take care of my head", can I idenfity that my user find one Doctor (Fabio) but with Synonymous and not return something like this:

"I found the doctor Fabio that take care of head"??

tks

Comment: What is the expected outcome you want to see?

Comment: I want to understand that's my user typed one synonym from doctor Fabio instead the doctor Fabio

Comment: If only this doctor take care of those specialties, I think you just need to response something direct in the dialog like: "I found the doc Fabio that take care of @Doctors". But I think it is better to create 2 entities (@nameDoctor and @Specialties), because you may have more than one doctor that takes care of the same problem

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact text that was matched by the entity, you can use `.literal` accessor that will return the exact text matched by the entity. 
In your example that would be `@Doctors.literal`. For more information, see WCS documentation.